# crossing two different datasets to mutate and summarise results from one dataset into another

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Say I have this fake data frame
[image: fake_ds]

and also have this "external_table" here:

[image: table]

I would like to "synchronize" both datasets to add a new column to the external_table a new column, via the following process:

1. access the fake_ds
2. perform a function into the items from external_table %>% itens_fator
3. Mutate the results into the external table

My desired output (with fake results)
[image: desired output]

That's the pseudo-function the script should perform:

```
fake_ds %>%  #get my ds
  mutate(cronbach_alpha = fake_ds %>% 
           select(external_table, itens_fator) %>% 
           alpha(.)$total[1]) #get variables from external table
```

If this function is hard to implement, I'll open to other approaches that yield the desired output as well.

I would like to remain with tidyverse.

Code to recreate my data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x <- paste0("y",seq(1:96)) #create X
y <- rep(0:5, 96*2) #create values
fake_ds <- data.frame(x,y) #dataframe
fake_ds %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from=y, values_fn = {mean}) -> fake_ds
fake_ds <- fake_ds %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = 50)) #replicate
fake_ds <- rbind(fake_ds, seq(1:96)) #add variability
    
#external table
external_table <- structure(list(
  name = c("X5", "X1", "X2", "X0", "X3", "X4"), 
  itens_fator = c("y1,y12,y59,y76,y78,y92,y93,y94,y96", 
                  "y5,y14,y15,y16,y17,y18,y20,y24,y40,y60,y62,y64,y75", 
                  "y10,y19,y32,y34,y36,y37,y47,y56,y58,y72,y80,y85", 
                  "y13,y30,y39,y53,y54,y55,y66,y73,y84,y91", 
                  "y42,y43,y45,y63,y69,y77,y87,y88", 
                  "y44,y49,y50,y68,y82,y89")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
  groups = structure(list(name = c("X0", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), 
                          .rows = structure(list(4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L), 
                                            ptype = integer(0), 
                                            class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                      "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                     .drop = TRUE), 
  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: what you're trying to achieve is basically impossible with mutate `the number of items you have is different from the number of rows` and it doesn't make any sense to append em to the dataframe the way you're doing

Comment: also the pivot wider code fails

Comment: So, it's not possible to select the variables displayed in "external_table" in the "fake_ds"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments what you're trying to achieve is impossible .... To get the cronbach's alphas all you need to do is use lapply with strsplit..

## getting the cronbach's alphas

```
lapply(strsplit(external_table$itens_fator,","), function(x) fake_ds %>% 
           select(all_of(x)) %>% 
           alpha(.)%>% .$total %>% .$raw_alpha)
```

### tidy way

```
external_table$itens_fator %>% strsplit(",") %>% purrr::map_dbl(function(x) fake_ds %>% 
           select(all_of(x)) %>% 
           psych::alpha(.)%>% .$total %>% .$raw_alpha)
```

## Data

```
library(psych)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x <- paste0("y",seq(1:96)) #create X
y <- rep(0:5, 96*2) #create values
fake_ds <- data.frame(var=x,val=y) #dataframe
fake_ds %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from=val, values_fn=list(val=mean)) -> fake_ds
fake_ds <- fake_ds %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = 50)) #replicate
fake_ds <- rbind(fake_ds, seq(1:96)) #add variability
    
#external table
external_table <- structure(list(
  name = c("X5", "X1", "X2", "X0", "X3", "X4"), 
  itens_fator = c("y1,y12,y59,y76,y78,y92,y93,y94,y96", 
                  "y5,y14,y15,y16,y17,y18,y20,y24,y40,y60,y62,y64,y75", 
                  "y10,y19,y32,y34,y36,y37,y47,y56,y58,y72,y80,y85", 
                  "y13,y30,y39,y53,y54,y55,y66,y73,y84,y91", 
                  "y42,y43,y45,y63,y69,y77,y87,y88", 
                  "y44,y49,y50,y68,y82,y89")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
  groups = structure(list(name = c("X0", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), 
                          .rows = structure(list(4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L), 
                                            ptype = integer(0), 
                                            class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                      "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                     .drop = TRUE), 
  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. This part (lapply(strsplit(external_table$itens_fator,",")) just solved my problem and I could replace more than 50 lines with your solution. Thanks much also for your patient. One minor comment, just for my personal understanding, could you please point me where I can learn to translate the lapply with a tidyverse routine?

Comment: @Luis I guess this is as tidy as it could get

Comment: it's my pleasure @Luis check the edit. I used `purr:map_dbl` so that it coerces the output to a double vector.